# Two CnR with same CnR idea

Tags: discussion, cops-and-robbers

I had the idea to make a CnR where the cops present non-golfed code and the robbers present the golfed version. I found out it was a dupe :( but wanted to know.

If you have a CnR challenge and make another with a different task but the core challenge is it a dupe?

Comment: This question is not very clear.  Please specify exactly what you intend to ask.

Comment: @WheatWizard Sorry it took a while to even word it how it was.

Answer (score 3):

## We measure [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) duplicates by the "core challenge", not the "arbitrary task"

For example, in [The Programming Language Quiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz), the core challenge is "writing a program such that it is hard to identify the language", while the task is "writing a Hello World! program"

A different Programming Language Quiz but with a different task (e.g. print the fibonacci sequence) is definitely a duplicate.

If the task contributes to the core challenge in some way, then there is some leeway, but it is up to close-voters to judge how similar they are.